# PHP can't call class method more than once

Tags: php, class, oop, pdo

As a beginner in this PHP OOP classes world I need some help to understand what I've been doing wrong and what I can do better.

I have the following code for my database connection:

```
class ConexaoPDO_PTA
{
    private $host_pdo_pta    = DB_HOST_PTA;
    private $dbname_pdo_pta  = DB_NAME_PTA;
    private $user_pdo_pta    = DB_USER_PTA;
    private $pass_pdo_pta    = DB_PASS_PTA;
    private $dbh;
    private $error;

    public function __construct(){
        $dsn = 'odbc:Driver={SQL Server}; Server='.$this->host_pdo_pta.'; Database='.$this->dbname_pdo_pta.';';

        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        try
        {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user_pdo_pta, $this->pass_pdo_pta, $options);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function query($query){
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function fetchAllAssoc(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function fetchAssoc(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function fetchAllObj(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    public function fetchObj(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    public function rowCount(){
        return count($this->stmt->fetchAll());
    }

    public function debugDumpParams(){
        return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
    }

    public function closeConnection(){
        return $this->dbh = null;
    }
}
```

That works just fine.
Then I was trying to make this to generate a graphic data:

```
class DadosGraph extends ConexaoPDO_PTA
{

    public $_data;
    public $_diaMes;
    public $_mesAno;
    public $_exibirData;

    public $_dataInicial;
    public $_dataFinal;

    public $_tipoEmpresa;
    public $_visao;
    public $_linha1;
    public $_linha2;
    public $_linha3;
    public $_comporLinhas;


    public function visao($visao)
    {
        switch($visao)
        {
            case 'vs1':
                $this->_visao = "VS1";
            break;
            case 'vs2':
                $this->_visao = "VS2";
            break;
            case 'vs3':
                $this->_visao = "VS3";
            break;
            case 'vs4':
                $this->_visao = "VS4";
            break;

            default:
                $this->_visao = null;
            break;
        }
    }


    public function defineData($varData)
    {
        list($mes, $dia, $ano) = explode("/", $varData);
        $this->_exibirData  = $dia."/".$mes;
        $this->_data        = $mes."/".$dia."/".$ano;
        $this->_diaMes      = $dia."/".$mes;
        $this->_mesAno      = $mes."/".$ano;
    }

    public function defineTipoEmpresa($TipoEmpresa = null, $Empresa = null)
    {
        if(($TipoEmpresa != null) AND ($Empresa != null)):
            $this->_tipoEmpresa = ", @".$TipoEmpresa." = '".$Empresa."'";
        else:
            $this->_tipoEmpresa = null;
        endif;
    }


    public function gerarGrafico()
    {
        $arrTotal = array_replace_recursive($this->_linha1, $this->_linha2, $this->_linha3);

        $result = array();
        foreach ($arrTotal as $key => $value) {
            $horario = $value['Hora'].":59";

            if( $value['Hora'] >= date("H", time()) ):
                $TarifaTotalHoje = null;
            else:
                $TarifaTotalHoje = ', "data3":"'.$value['TarifaTotal_linha3'].'"';
            endif;

            $TarifaTotalSP = ', "data1":"'.$value['TarifaTotal_linha1'].'"';
            $TarifaTotalOntem = ', "data2":"'.$value['TarifaTotal_linha2'].'"';

            echo '{ "category": "'.$horario.'"'.$TarifaTotalSP.''.$TarifaTotalOntem.''.$TarifaTotalHoje.' },<br>';
        }
    }


    public function linha($linha, $data, $horaInicial, $horaFinal)
    {

        $this->_dataInicial = $data." ".$horaInicial;
        $this->_dataFinal = $data." ".$horaFinal;

        $this->query("execute spBilhetesEmitidosporEmpresa @Acao = '".$this->_visao."', @DataHoraVenda = '".$this->_dataInicial."', @DataHoraVendaFinal = '".$this->_dataFinal."' ".$this->_tipoEmpresa."");
        $this->execute();
        $SelectDiaSPReceita = $this->fetchAllAssoc();

        $ord = array();
        foreach ($SelectDiaSPReceita as $value){
            $ord[] = strtotime( $value['DataHoraVenda'] );
        }

        array_multisort($ord, SORT_ASC, $SelectDiaSPReceita);

        $i = 0;
        $arrChavesHorarios = array();
        while ($i < 2400) {
            $a = sprintf("%04d", $i);
            $hora = substr( $a, 0, 2);

            $horario = $hora.":00";
            $arrChavesHorarios[] = $horario;

            $i = $i + 100;
        }

        $i = 0;
        $arrN = array();
        while ($i < 24) {
            $arrN[] = $i;
            $i++;
        }

        $arrCombine = array_combine($arrChavesHorarios, $arrN);

        $arrayDiaSP = array();
        foreach ($SelectDiaSPReceita as $value) {
            $hora = substr( $value['DataHoraVenda'] , 11, -10);
            $dia = substr( $value['DataHoraVenda'] , 8, -13);
            $mes = substr( $value['DataHoraVenda'] , 5, -16);
            $ano = substr( $value['DataHoraVenda'] , 0, -19);

            if(isset($arrayDiaSP[$hora.":00"])):
                $arrayDiaSP[$hora.":00"]['BilhetesVendidos']++;
                $arrayDiaSP[$hora.":00"]['TarifaTotal'] += $value['TotalEmissao'];
            else:
                $arrayDiaSP[$hora.":00"] = array( "Dia" => $dia, "Mes" => $mes, "Ano" => $ano, "Hora" => $hora, "BilhetesVendidos" => 1, "TarifaTotal" => number_format($value['TotalEmissao'], 2) );
            endif;
        }


        $arrZeradosSP = array();
        foreach ($arrChavesHorarios as $value) {
            if( !array_key_exists($value, $arrayDiaSP) ):
                list($hora, $min) = explode(":", $value);
                $arrZeradosSP[$value] = array( "Dia" => 0, "Mes" => 0, "Ano" => 0, "Hora" => $hora, "BilhetesVendidos" => 0, "TarifaTotal" => number_format(0, 2) );
            endif;
        }

        $arrayMerge1 = array_merge_recursive($arrayDiaSP, $arrZeradosSP);
        $arrayDiaSPNovo = array_combine(array_merge($arrayMerge1, $arrCombine), $arrayMerge1);
        ksort($arrayDiaSPNovo);

        $bilhetesVendidos = 0;
        $tarifaTotal      = 0;

        $arrTotalSP = array();
        foreach ($arrayDiaSPNovo as &$entry) {
            $bilhetesVendidos += $entry['BilhetesVendidos'];
            $tarifaTotal      += $entry['TarifaTotal'];

            $entry['BilhetesVendidos'] = $bilhetesVendidos;
            $entry['TarifaTotal']      = $tarifaTotal;

            $arrTotalSP[] = array("Dia" => $entry["Dia"], "Mes" => $entry["Mes"], "Ano" => $entry["Ano"], "Hora" => $entry["Hora"], "BilhetesVendidos".$linha => $entry["BilhetesVendidos"], "TarifaTotal".$linha => number_format( $entry["TarifaTotal"] , 2, ".", "") );
        }

        $this->$linha = $arrTotalSP;
    }

}
```

When I run something like:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once("../classes/class.autoload.inc.php");

echo "<pre>Up and running!</pre><br><br>";

$test = new DadosGraph;
$test -> visao("vs3");
$test -> defineTipoEmpresa();

$test -> defineData("10/05/2015");
$test -> linha("_linha1", $test->_data, "00:00:00", "23:59:59");

$test -> defineData("10/16/2015");
$test -> linha("_linha2", $test->_data, "00:00:00", "23:59:59");

$test -> defineData( date("m/d/Y") );
$test -> linha("_linha3", $test->_data, "00:00:00", "23:59:59");

$test -> gerarGrafico();

echo "<br><br>";

$obj = new DadosGraph;
$obj -> visao("vs3");
$obj -> defineTipoEmpresa("Empresa", "nome_emp");

$obj -> defineData("10/05/2015");
$obj -> linha("_linha1", $obj->_data, "00:00:00", "23:59:59");

$obj -> defineData("10/16/2015");
$obj -> linha("_linha2", $obj->_data, "00:00:00", "23:59:59");

$obj -> defineData( date("m/d/Y") );
$obj -> linha("_linha3", $obj->_data, "00:00:00", "23:59:59");

$obj -> gerarGrafico();
```

In this case above, the `$test` runs and prints me the result, but the `$obj` shows me the error below:

```
Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\class.ConexaoPDO_PTA.inc.php on line 59
```

The line 59 in that file is the line below:

```
    public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }
```

If I run the `$obj` separately, it runs fine, but not just after that one. What am I missing? Basically, if I wanna run N times the class `DadosGraph` I'll be not able to do so?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

There's a huge mistake in your design: DadosGraph should not inherit from ConexaoPDO_PTA.

Usually OOP-CRUD is done in a fundamentally different way:

1. Create and maintain a ConexaoPDO_PTA
2. Use said connection to run queries against a database
3. Take the data from queries and put them into DadosGraph

Right now you're doing it like if DadosGraph is a kind of ConexaoPDO_PTA and that's wrong.

Comment: So, basically I've been doing sh*t this whole time... lol. Thank you for the tips, I know I gotta read more about it. I confess I thought that "extends" means something like "put together" to run both easier.

Comment: What you could also do is to separate them, initialize the connection and pass its instance as a parameter for DadosGraph class @Edson